# How To Extract Any String If It Starts With An Uppercase Letter

Tags: regex

I have a list of queries and I'm trying to identify all the queries that begin with an upper case letter using regex:

- ipad
- Food
- Beauty, Spa & Health
- Green Shoe
- fudge

So the regex should identify the following queries from the list above:

- Food
- Beauty, Spa & Health
- Green Shoe

I'm not really sure why this doesn't work:

```
REGEX(query_string, "^[A-Z]+$\b")
```

I'm using regex inside of Platfora if that helps:

http://documentation.platfora.com/webdocs/index.html#reference/regular_expressions/regex_ref_top.html

I would appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: Your regex only finds strings starting with an upper case letter and containing only upper case letters.  How are the strings separated?

Comment: The strings are just in a field within a DB.  There is only one string within a field.  I'm just looking for all the fields which contain an upper case letter.

Comment: `(^|\b)[A-Z]` should work in your case

Comment: @hjpotter92 this would also match `not Capital`

Comment: @davidrac OP says "_I'm just looking for all the fields which contain an upper case letter_."

Comment: Bit confusing that bit - in the question the OP is looking for '_queries that begin with an upper case letter_'  Based on the original question, the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to test if the string begins with a capital letter, then this is enough:

```
"^[A-Z]"
```

The problem with your regex is that is will only match strings that begin with capital letters up until a word boundary, which is not what you're after.